# Как поставить такой маркер + текст, Yandex Maps APi?

Tags: карты, яндекс-карты

ставлю яндекс карту по Api. Каким образом можно ставить такой маркер + названия как на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Желательно добавить код инициализации карты (без токена)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если такое изображение есть в открытом доступе, вы можете использовать его в качестве метки.
Подробнее в [примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage) в песочнице.

```
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
        balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
        iconImageSize: [30, 42],
        iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
    })
```